# Laravel 5.3 pagination on sortBy collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

Why the paginate method doesn't work on this example ?

```
$shopIds = Follower::whereUserId($user->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->pluck('shop_id')->toArray();
            $shops = Shop::whereIn('id',$shopIds)->with('deals')->with('deals.likes')->paginate($this->perPage)->sortBy(function($likes) {
                return $likes->count();
            });
            dd($shops);
```

[image]

Thank's for help ;)

Comment: whats the error here?

Comment: There's no error but if I use paginate() method or get() method, it's the same result. Results are not paginated, so I don't understand why.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `paginate` is just working fine but the `sortBy` method is creating the problem for you because when you use `sortBy` it returns a new collection.

So finally your `$shops` is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` not of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`.

You can try it as:

```
$paginated_shops = Shop::whereIn('id',$shopIds)
                  ->with('deals')
                  ->with('deals.likes')
                  ->paginate($this->perPage);

$shops = $paginated_shops->sortBy(function($likes) {
        return $likes->count();
    });

$shops = new LengthAwarePaginator($shops, $paginated_shops->total(), $paginated_shops->perPage());
```

Remember to add `use` statement at the top of the class as:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

Comment: This helped me in 2021 :) Thanks alot.

Comment: This helped me in 2023 :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys!

I fix it like that

```
$shopIds = Follower::whereUserId($user->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->pluck('shop_id')->toArray();
            $shopIds = Shop::whereIn('id',$shopIds)->with('deals')->with('deals.likes')->get()->sortBy(function($likes) {
                return $likes->count();
            })->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $orderedIds = implode(',',$shopIds);
            $shops = Shop::whereIn('id', $shopIds)->whereNotIn('user_id', [$user->id])->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".$orderedIds." )"))->paginate($this->perPage);
            dd($shops);
```

and now I have an instance of Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
[image]

Thank's

Comment: You don't need to do a new query. You have all the data for pagination. It's a redundant query. Check my updated answer, it may solve your problem without doing an extra query.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Amit mentionned, $shops is a collection, thus not a LengthAwarePaginator.  You are going to have to build the paginator and slice it yourself... not too complicated...

For example, let's assume you are hitting your route, calling your controller... then returning results to a view... Now that route is going to get requested with the pagination info in the request, you job is to get the result $shops into an array, slice the array into the right result for the page and return that to your view... I have not run this code... so take this as an example... but it will look something like:

```
public function yourController{

    // This will return a collection... we will convert it to array later
    $shops = Shop::whereIn('id',$shopIds)->with('deals')->with('deals.likes')->paginate($this->perPage)->sortBy(function($likes) {
            return $likes->count();
        });

    $shopsArray = $shops->toArray();

    // Here we deal with the slicing... you need to slice the page you are
    // at the paging info is in the request... 

    // this basically gets the request's page variable... or defaults to 1
    $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage('page') ?: 1;

    // Assume 15 items per page... so start index to slice our array
    $startIndex = ($page - 1) * 15;

    // Length aware paginator needs a total count of items... to paginate properly
    $total = count($shopsArray);

    // Eliminate the non relevant items by slicing the array to page content...
    $results = array_slice($shopsArray, $startIndex, 15);

    $result =  new LengthAwarePaginator($results, $total, 15, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => 'page',
    ]);
    return view('yourView', compact('result'));
}
```